# .ipynbファイルを.pyファイルへの変換

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

[図解！Jupyter Labを徹底解説！(インストール・使い方・拡張機能)](https://ai-inter1.com/jupyter-lab/#wrapper) を参照して、.ipynbファイルを.pyファイルの変換を試みましたが、上手く出来ません。

実行すると、下記の図が表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

”エクスプローラー”には、下記の通り表示。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上、参照サイトに基づいて行いましたが、.pyファイルは作成できません。
"02.ipynb"をクリックしてみましたが…ダメでした。
検索をしてみましたが、解決にいたる結果を得ることは出来ませんでした。
ご教授お願いします。

参考までにコードを添付します。

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\chromedriver.exe") # Windows
url = 'https://scraping-for-beginner.herokuapp.com/login_page'
browser.get(url)
elem_username = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
elem_username.send_keys('imanishi')
elem_password = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
elem_password.send_keys('kohei')
browser.quit()
```

Comment: そのスクリーンショットはMicrosoft Edgeだと思われますが、この辺の機能に引っかかっていたりしませんか？ [潜在的に危険なファイルのダウンロードを中断する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-downloads-interruptions), [Microsoft Edge　パスワード マネージャーのセキュリティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-password-manager-security) この辺の何かモードを変えるオプションがあれば操作してみるとか、またはシステムのデフォルトのブラウザをChromeに変えてみるとか？ あるいはJupyter LabのGUIではなくコマンドプロンプトで変換してみるとか？ [ipynb ファイルを py ファイルに変換する方法](https://fujiyamaegg.com/python-ipynb-to-py/)

Comment: 「.ipynbファイルを.pyファイルの変換を試みました」とのことですが、質問者さんが実際に行った操作を具体的に説明お願いいたします。

Comment: エクスポート (保存) 自体は出来ているけど、ブラウザからそのまま開こうとして実行をブロックされているようにも見えます。エクスポート時に指定したフォルダの中も念のため確認してみてください。

Comment: "ipynb ファイルを py ファイルに変換する方法"参照して、無事.py変換になりました。ありがとうございました。尚、利用したコマンドプロンプトは、"Anaconda Prompt(anakonda3)"です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントにて解決ということで回答として記録。

以下の記事を応用して、Jupyter LabのGUIでの操作の代りにAnaconda Prompt(anakonda3)でのコマンドプロンプトにより変換出来たとのこと。
[ipynb ファイルを py ファイルに変換する方法](https://fujiyamaegg.com/python-ipynb-to-py/)

> やり方
> コマンドにより変換を行います。
>
> １ファイルを変換する場合
>
> ```
> jupyter nbconvert --to python xxxx.ipynb
> (xxxxに個別の名称)
> ```

---

参考：
質問のスクリーンショットはおそらくMicrosoft Edgeのダウンロードのメッセージボックスのようなので、以下のようなブラウザによるファイルダウンロード時のチェックに引っかかったと思われます。
[潜在的に危険なファイルのダウンロードを中断する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-downloads-interruptions)
[Microsoft Edge エンドポイントの許可リスト](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-endpoints)
[Microsoft Edge - ポリシー](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies)
[Microsoft Edge　パスワード マネージャーのセキュリティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-password-manager-security)

これらのチェックを外すか一時的に無効にするオプションやモード設定があれば、それを探して試してみることも考えられます。
あるいはChromeやFireFox等の、同様のチェック機能があっても違うブラウザということで動作が出来るかもしれないのを期待して、システムのデフォルトブラウザを変えてみるという手も考えられます。

---

質問時に行った動作は参照記事の下の方にある、Jupyter LabのFileメニューによるExport処理でしょう。
[Jupyter Labで.pyファイルの作成・保存と実行方法](https://ai-inter1.com/jupyter-lab/#st-toc-h-17)
[.pyファイルの作成・保存方法](https://ai-inter1.com/jupyter-lab/#st-toc-h-18)

> Pythonの実行ファイルである.pyファイルを作成・保存するには、画面左上のメニュー「File」から「Export Notebook As」を選択し、右横に表示されたメニューから「Export Notebook to Executable Script」を選択して下さい。